# MoveIt undefined reference when declared inside the function

Tags: moveit, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am using  Using ROS Kinetic, Ubuntu 16.04.
I try to create a variable of MoveGroupInterface in my class as:

```
#include <moveit/move_group_interface/move_group_interface.h>

Class Test{
private:
    moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface right_arm;    
}
```

It throws me the following error. I suspected its a linking error, however, I checked my CmakeLists.txt and I guess it looks fine:

Error:

```
/home/artc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsw_lib.so: undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::MoveGroupInterface(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, boost::shared_ptr<tf::Transformer> const&, ros::WallDuration const&)'
/home/artc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/libsw_lib.so: undefined reference to `moveit::planning_interface::MoveGroupInterface::~MoveGroupInterface()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
sawyer_robot/sawyer_interface/CMakeFiles/sw_node.dir/build.make:179: recipe for target '/home/artc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sawyer_interface/sw_node' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/artc/catkin_ws/devel/lib/sawyer_interface/sw_node] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:7765: recipe for target 'sawyer_robot/sawyer_interface/CMakeFiles/sw_node.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [sawyer_robot/sawyer_interface/CMakeFiles/sw_node.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:138: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

CmakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(sawyer_interface)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -g")

include(CheckCXXCompilerFlag)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++11" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
CHECK_CXX_COMPILER_FLAG("-std=c++0x" COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
if(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX11)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
elseif(COMPILER_SUPPORTS_CXX0X)
    set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++0x")
else()
        message(STATUS "The compiler ${CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER} has no C++11 support. Please use a different C++ compiler.")
endif()

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  
  moveit_core 
  moveit_ros_planning 
  moveit_ros_planning_interface 
  moveit_visual_tools
  intera_core_msgs
  geometry_msgs
  cmake_modules
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  message_generation
  
)

find_package(Eigen3 REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system thread)

catkin_package(
   CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp rospy std_msgs moveit_ros_planning  moveit_ros_planning_interface moveit_core trajectory_msgs   
   INCLUDE_DIRS include 
   LIBRARIES tcp_comms
  
)

include_directories(include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} 
  ${EIGEN3_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_library(sw_lib
  src/sw.cpp
)

add_dependencies(sw_lib ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})


add_executable(sw_node src/sw_node.cpp)
add_dependencies(sw_node ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS} sw_lib)
target_link_libraries(sw_node ${catkin_LIBRARIES} sw_lib)


install(TARGETS sw_lib sw_node
  ARCHIVE DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  LIBRARY DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_LIB_DESTINATION}
  RUNTIME DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_BIN_DESTINATION}
)

install(
  DIRECTORY include/${PROJECT_NAME}
  DESTINATION include
)


install(DIRECTORY launch/
  DESTINATION ${CATKIN_PACKAGE_SHARE_DESTINATION}/launch
  PATTERN ".svn" EXCLUDE)


if(CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING)
    find_package(rostest REQUIRED)

endif()
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/271211/moveit-undefined-reference-when-declared-inside-the-function/) by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on ROS Answers with karma: 277 on 2017-09-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [v4hn](https://answers.ros.org/users/4809/v4hn/) on 2017-09-26**:
At first glance nothing looks wrong - although the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS code is a mess...

Is your package.xml correct and updated? See https://answers.ros.org/question/271431/some-errors-occurred-when-package-was-compilinglink-error/?answer=271515#post-id-271515

Sadly I can't test this right now.

**Comment by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) on 2017-09-26**:
Hi, @v4hn Michael, I have already zipped and attached my package in the moveit user's group. You should be able to catkin_make and be able to reproduce this error. I have been through all these, and I guess my package.xml is right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is resolved, by just linking my own library with `target_link_libraries(sw_lib ${catkin_LIBRARIES})`

---

Originally posted by [arunavanag](https://answers.ros.org/users/29343/arunavanag/) with karma: 277 on 2017-10-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1